# Improper usage of chat in SO?

Tags: discussion, chat

It's not the first time that I receive chat invitations for job offering or asking help privately. This time, I kindly offered the user to ask a question on SO, to which he replied that he **can't** because he wants to know "from starting", he's new to the subject and wants to learn.

Personally, I don't think it's proper to use chat to ask for private tutoring (or questions), but I also used to think that adding tags in the title is OK even if not necessary for readability.
So, is it a proper usage? Please enlighten me.

Comment: Just ignore the user. If he keep harassing you flag the offensive messages and he'll hopefully be kicked out of chat and eventually get suspended if he won't stop.

Comment: Yeah, just ignore them. It's okay to ask such stuff in chat; most often, the request will simply be ignored. **Repeatedly** asking is not okay, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you told them you aren't interested (in their job offer or privately helping them) once and they didn't get it, you can always use the "ignore this user(everywhere)" feature

[image: ignore this user(everywhere)]

A little known, but *extremely* useful feature.

Comment: What is the effect? Does it also hides questions/answers by this user? Also, using this option alone will not let the user know that he's doing something wrong.

Comment: @Noich It will hide all their messages (from you), and their chat avatar in the sidebar (when they are online) will be smaller (a visual hint that you are actively ignoring the user). They won't get any notification about being ignored, and they may still `@username` message you (but you won't notice). So... no, this option won't let them know that they are doing something wrong. But if you've already told them once that you are not interested and they continue, it's a good enough option. You can't educate someone who isn't interested in being educated.

Comment: I discovered this one recently, and I have to admit - the effect is perfect.  All the noise from the annoying user drops out of the chat room display. I noticed that you can still see when people address the ignored person, but that's a minor nuisance.

Comment: I've used the ignore feature once, and unignored some time later (hours), and I haven't regretted. Some people do learn.

Comment: Though many have tried, some have failed! Winner!

Comment: awesome feature, Yannis.  Yannis?  Hello, Yannis?